# query about installing Python package

Tags: python, mechanize, ipython

I have installed ipython on my Ubuntu and then I have installed mechanize on the same.
I can able to do

```
import mechanize
```

from command prompt. But when I say import mechanize from ipython, it says as no module named mechanize.

Comment: check for where it (mechanize) is installed and confirm whether it is accessible n PYTHON_PATH

Comment: @harshith  : paths are different
burhan : no

Comment: and i dont understand how its possible that i can import from command but cant import from ipython

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this...

In the console:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> mechanize.__file__
Some/path/to/mechanize
```

Then in IPython,

```
[1] import sys
[2] print sys.path
```

See if the /Some/path/to/mechanize is in your sys.path.

Comment: thanks it is not in the sys.path. can you tell me how i can add them in sys,path in ubuntu permanently??

Comment: Put this line in  `~\.bashrc` file `export PYTHONPATH=<your path to mechanize>`. This one line command should do the job: `$ echo "export PYTHONPATH=<your path to mechanize>" >> ~\.bashrc`. Then restart your OS and check.

Comment: @HarshithJ.V. : i tried same as you explained & also restart the system. still same error

Comment: What does `mechanize.__file__` give you?